# Update last field with value from line count (awk?)

Tags: awk

I have a pipe delimited file (file.001) as below:

```
00|FIELD10|FIELD02
01|FIELD01|FIELD02|FIELD03
01|FIELD01|FIELD02|FIELD03
01|FIELD01|FIELD02|FIELD03
01|FIELD01|FIELD02|FIELD03
99|4
```

The lines beginning with '01' are the records (00 = header, 99 = trailer). The last field in the trailer (currently populated with '4') is the record count, however this record count is not always accurate.

What I want to do is count the number of records and update the record count field while leaving the rest of the data untouched (printing to a new file would be fine, ideally it would be within the same file). My interpretation of this would be to print the count value into the last field value but I don't know how to do this.

I have been attempting this with awk and currently have the following for printing the count and the last field:

Print record count:

```
awk '/^01/ {count++} END {print count }' file.001
```

Print last field:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="|"}; END {print ($(NF))}' file.001
```

Could anyone offer a suggestion on how to do this?
I am new to awk so apologies if what I have above so far isn't very good. I am also open to using something other than awk to achieve this.

Comment: Mmmm can you indicate what's your desired output?

Comment: The output would be how the file is now. The issue I have is that I could maybe have 1000 '01' records in the file but the file count at the bottom could be '4'. I would like to count those 1000 records and update '4' to '1000'. Obvioulsy this could be done with a count and then update the file by hand but I could have 100 files at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your first `awk` statement, I'm surprised you didn't use something like this to print the last field (count of records):

```
awk -F '|' '/^99/ { print $NF }' file
```

The 'trailer' always begins with '99', correct? So you can use this to make the desired changes to your file. Perhaps try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } $1 == "01" { c++ } $1 == "99" { $2 = c }1' file
```

---

---

If you have the latest `gawk`, you can use 'in-place' editing:

```
gawk -i inplace '...' file
```

Note that this is the same as:

```
gawk '...' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works perfectly :) Like I say I'm new to awk so I had a feeling I was getting close but I wasn't sure exactly what to do. Thanks again :)